# MySQL LIMIT 0,15 where 15 is the number of parent_ids, not children

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I've got a table and I'm trying to fetch comments for ajax pagination.

You can see a SQLFiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d36a/1

But basically, without the `LIMIT` of `0,15`, it works as intended:

E.g. All comments that are children will be displayed with/under the parent comments.

The problem comes when I introduce the `LIMIT`. In the example above, it'll fetch 15 comments, but because the 16th comment is a child of comment with `id=6`, it won't be returned. If you change it to `LIMIT 0,16`, it'll be returned properly.

Basically I want to return ONLY `0,15` parent comments at a time, but unlimited child comments.

I was told to try a temporary table, but then someone else told me that it could be much simpler (and using only one join with an inner select), but I'm just a little confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make it work using the following query :

```
SELECT 
  comment.id,
  comment.deleted,
  comment.comment,
  comment.user_id,
  comment.created,
  comment.parent_id,
  s.id as sid,
  s.user_id submissionUserId,
  u.username,
  u.photo AS userPhoto
FROM (SELECT c.* 
      FROM submissions_comments AS c
      WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL
      ORDER BY c.created DESC
      LIMIT 0, 15) AS base
LEFT JOIN submissions_comments AS comment ON (
  comment.parent_id = base.id 
  OR comment.id = base.id
)
LEFT JOIN users u ON comment.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN submissions s ON comment.submission_id = s.id
WHERE base.deleted = 0
ORDER BY base.created DESC
```

You can see it in action : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d90f5/1

But I don't know if it will be efficient on the performance side.

What it does basically is :

- Grab the 15 first parent comments in a sub query (or inner query)
- For each of those grab the children *and* a copy of the parent

Comment: At least the ` c.parent_id IS NULL` is wrong. It must be part of some ORDER BY part like in the original query.

Comment: @FabianBarney why is it wrong ? in the subquery I want only the parents, no child. Care to explain ? Did you had a look at the sqlfiddle ? it seems to me that it is working just fine.

Comment: This looks pretty good. Can performance be improved on this? If so, how would I benchmark/improve it? Replacing the inner SELECT with a UNION or something?

Comment: @FabianBarney is right. This has the parents ordered wrong for some reason.

Comment: @krtek I'll hook it up with the +200 if you can help me figure this out.

Comment: Just change `ORDER BY created` to `ORDER BY c.created DESC` (`DESC` is the important part - I only added the `c.` for clarity).  In addition, `ORDER BY base.created DESC, comment.created` should be added to the main query to help guarantee the order of the "reply" comments is correct.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d36a/81  I would have made my own answer to this question, but I feel @krtek did the heavy lifting here and felt it would be bad form to claim credit for what I consider a minor edit.

Comment: @bob_cobb I updated the answer with the suggestion from Starson. The order seems good to me now. Feel free to give any more feedback !

Comment: I think it's pretty close, but SID, and SUBMISSIONUSERID shouldn't be null? Also where should I check for submission_id = [num]? In both base.submission_id and where else?

Comment: @krtek Actually, for some reason, the username is not maintaing the proper relation as well. Do I need to order by something? E.g. if I reply to a comment, it will insert fine, but when doing the join for the username of that comment, the userPhoto and username are wrong (e.g. they are showing the parent, it seems?)

Comment: @bob_cobb Ok, I see what you mean, there was some minor errors in the SQL code. I edited it and linked to a new jsfiddle. Hope everything is alright now !

Comment: Amazing. Thank you to @StarsonHochschild and you! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
SELECT sc.id,
  sc.deleted,
  sc.comment,
  sc.user_id,
  sc.created,
  sc.parent_id,
  s.id as sid,
  s.user_id submissionUserId,
  u.username,
  u.photo AS userPhoto,
  coalesce(p.id, sc.id) as ocol1,
  coalesce(p.created, sc.created) as ocol2
FROM submissions_comments AS sc
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON sc.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN submissions AS s ON sc.submission_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN submissions_comments AS p on p.id = sc.parent_id
where coalesce(p.id, sc.id) between 0 and 15
and sc.deleted = 0
ORDER BY ocol1, ocol2
```

Obviously, this is using the id column to 'paginate' the rows - if they are frequently deleted, this could leave a page sparse or empty. I may have a stab at altering it to select a given number of parents, not just a range. If you are interested in this approach, feel free to clarify your requirements in this area.